# Pokemon-related mods for Minecraft PE server running on Raspberry Pi

Tags: minecraft

I would like to run a Minecraft PE server on Raspberry Pi so that one can connect to it from iOS and Android devices. Also, I am looking for Pokemon-related mods (not necessarily Pokemon-GO) that can be installed on that server and be playable from the mobile clients. As far as I see, [Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org) or [Nukkit](http://nukkit.io) could work as such server, but I am not sure about installing mods and specifically Pokemon-related ones. Is it possible? Has anyone done it? What mods could work on such server?

Update: I have Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2

Answer (score 1):

I think your question might be better suited to either the Gaming Stack Exchange site or perhaps the Minecraft Forums.

You may struggle running an MCPE server on the Pi, although with a Pi 3 and few people not continuously setting off TNT, you may have a playable experience.

Comment: Yeah, hard to avoid TNT. Asked on gaming and got downvoted, so I guess Minecraft Forums then 